# Considering Ubuntu over Win 10

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

I'm being pushed away from XP.
Here are the programs I like most.  Will they run on Ubuntu?

1. Firefox
2. Lotus Word Pro
3. Ccleaner
4. Dfraggler
5. Nikon camera software
6. Old Printers software

Comment: *"Old Printers software"* is too vague. People will need to know your printer model to know if it's supported. Is *Ccleaner* something for cleaning up Windows Registry or something similar? If so it's not needed in Ubuntu which doesn't need periodic cleaning like Windows does.

Comment: Main issue may be Camera software. But I just copy files. Some cameras you can directly connect, others may need you to buy a $10 SD card reader and use that to copy files. In Linux you may end up doing things a bit differently, Sometimes better, sometimes not so much. Ubuntu has Firefox and it used LibreOffice for word processing & spreadsheets. Ubuntu is not Windows, do not try or expect to do everything the Windows way and you will find you like Ubuntu.

Comment: Firefox, LibreOffice Writer, BleachBit, e2fsprogs. For the camera and printer I recommend reading this question: [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu).

Comment: Also note that you can run Windows apps in GNU/Linux with Wine.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Ubuntu.
The answers to your question:

1. **Firefox** - yes
2. **Lotus Word Pro** - via Wine - see https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=6789  or as alternative Libreoffice
3. **Ccleaner** - not needed in Ubuntu - You will mostly install programs via package manager in Ubuntu, this keeps your system clean by default
4. **Dfraggler** - not needed in Ubuntu, the method of storing files in Linux file systems (EXT FS) is different than Windows NTFS
5. **Nikon camera software** - check this forum: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=191844
6. **Old Printers software** - depending on your printer model there might be a printer driver for linux available

Comment: Kukulo, Thanks for the help.  I almost overlooked your answer when I saw the reponse at the top "put on hold as too broad".  Right then I decided Ubuntu wasn't right for me but then saw your answer.  Broad questions often only allows a broad answer - a broad answer is still an answer. Thanks again Kukulo, Chris

Answer (score 2):

### Trying software out on Ubuntu before taking the plunge

One thing to keep in mind is that the Ubuntu (or Xubuntu or whatever flavor you're going for) installer DVD or USB drive you create has a `Try Ubuntu` option that starts running Ubuntu without touching your hard drive, so you can try things out.

You can even install things and write down what works for if you choose to install Ubuntu to your hard drive. The programs get installed into a RAM drive, so they don't touch your hard drive unless you open a file on your hard drive or something. So you can make sure that your camera software works or whatever else you want to try out. Just remember that if you run out of RAM, you can restart and try again.

### A few of the things you want

Firefox and a CCleaner alternative called BleachBit ([also available for Windows](https://www.bleachbit.org/download/windows)) are installable by opening the terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the following `sudo apt install` commands:

- Firefox: `sudo apt install firefox`
- CCleaner alternative BleachBit: `sudo apt install bleachbit`

These programs will then appear in the start-menu-like thing of whatever Ubuntu flavor you're using.